# Multiple images with same imageSource does not always load (Xamarin)

Tags: image, xamarin, xamarin.forms, imagesource

I have some problems with the images in one of my pages in Xamarin.Forms.

Basically, I have 5 stars lined up in a row, and the user can click on one of the stars to give a rating. I have 2 different images, one of a colored star, and another of a black star. If the user clicks on star number 3, star 1-3 will change to colored, and 4-5 will be black. If you select number 1, all but the first star will be black, and if you select the last star, all 5 stars will be colored.

This is my code:

```
    ImageSource ratingFill = ImageSource.FromResource("MyProject.Images.starfill.png");
    ImageSource ratingNoFill = ImageSource.FromResource("MyProject.Images.starnofill.png");
    private void ClickRating(int stars)
    {
        rating = stars;
        switch (stars)
        {
            case 1:
                rating1.Source = ratingFill;
                rating2.Source = ratingNoFill;
                rating3.Source = ratingNoFill;
                rating4.Source = ratingNoFill;
                rating5.Source = ratingNoFill;
                labelRatingText.Text = "Poor";
                break;
            case 2:
                rating1.Source = ratingFill;
                rating2.Source = ratingFill;
                rating3.Source = ratingNoFill;
                ...
        }
    }
```

It seems that not all 5 stars are updated when they should be. Its a bit random whether they load an image or not. Sometimes, if I click star 4, number 3 will just disappear (like it has no source). It seems there might be a problem using the same ImageSource multiple times, and at the same time.

Is this the wrong way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I think this behavior is getting weird because of the Bindings.

Try to change your `rating` variable declaration to this:

```
ImageSource ratingNoFill => ImageSource.FromResource("MyProject.Images.starnofill.png");
```

Comment: This actually worked! I have not seen this before. Is it the same as putting the ImageSource URI into each image.Source on each change instead of referencing the same source?

Comment: Actually this is like to do a by pass on the reference. Instead of just one instance of "ImageSource" it will get you a new instance on each reference to this variable. Was I clear?

Comment: Yes, its what I though. Cool, I didnt know this was possible :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling it like this?

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => ClickRating(stars));
```

Comment: This didn't work :( For the record, the images are usually loading, but occationally, one of the 5 disappears during a source change.